# When click on redux button, page is not re-render?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am playing with redux.
so `npm install, npm start`
It will popup a simple click button.

When I click the button, it is not re-render the home page. e.g. it should output 1

**Home.Container**

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { homeClickAction } from "./home.action";
import Home from "./Home";

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    homeClick: state.homeReducer.homeClick
  };
};

// const var
// dispatch
// return
// key
// data => { fire(actionCreator(data)) }
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    homeClickAction: data => {
      dispatch(homeClickAction(data));
    }
  };
};

const HomeContainer = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Home);

export default HomeContainer;
```

---

Store

```
// store
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';

// thunk
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

// root reducer
import rootReducer from './rootReducer';

// store
export default function configureStore() {
    return createStore(
        rootReducer,
        applyMiddleware(thunk)
    );
}
```

---

**rootReducer**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import homeReducer from './containers/Home/home.reducer';
export default combineReducers({
    homeReducer
});
```

Here is the [full code](https://github.com/kenpeter/test_container)

[image]

Comment: You have to be specific and post a portion of your code that may have a problem. Giving a link to a full repo and expecting someone to go in there and study the code just isn't right.

Comment: @16kb, yes you are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using combineReducers and you pass in your reducer as `homeReducer` to it. You need to also access the values from store by accessing `homeReducer` key first. So in `Home.Container's mapStateToProps` instead of writing `state.homeClick`, you would write `state.homeReducer.homeClick`

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    homeClick: state.homeReducer.homeClick
  };
};
```

[Working codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/l29y031j4z)